# iUI iPhone web app working on other devices

Tags: asp.net, iui

I am an asp.net developer looking to build a web app using iUI for the iPHone. I was wondering if this app would also display properly on other devices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Look at ASP.NET MVC.  The routing engine can use different views to render the page depending on the agent provided by the browser.  Hanselman has some great writes up on how this works:

[MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx)

[TheWeeklySourceCode28IPhoneWithASPNETMVCEdition](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode28IPhoneWithASPNETMVCEdition.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

iUI is based on HTML5 and CSS3. So yes, it will work on any device / desktop browser since it supports HTML5 and CSS3. Actually, only Webkit (Safari/Chrome/iPhone/Android) has a pretty good support of it, and Firefox 3.6 supports most of it too. Fennec 1.0 will.

Haven't heard if it was planned for IE9. Sure IE8 does not.